# Footable plugin pagination not working

Tags: pagination, footable

I have folowed the footable pagination example given [here](http://fooplugins.com/footable-demos/) 
But the pagination just doesnt work in my case.

the following is my code

```
<table id="exptab" class="table demo footable-loaded footable default" data-page-size="5">


  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody >
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>


  </tbody>
  <tfoot class="hide-if-no-paging">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5" class="text-center">
        <ul class="pagination">
        </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tfoot>

</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        debugger;
        $('table').footable();



    });

    </script>
```

Here for pagination i have even added a ul class="pagination" however this too just doesnt work. Could someone please point out as to what is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had finally fixed the problem a few months back. Adding the files they had in the footable repositary never worked for me somehow. I was baffled at how their examples worked neat , and mine didnt! 
So finally I decided to access their source code and get the files that were used by the examples directly and reference them in my code.

Voila! it started working like a charm :)

Please note: I had compared all the references in the examples many times , there was nothing at all that wasnt used by me ...yet the files that they used for their examples did the trick and the ones in their repositary never worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have included paginate add-on javascript file